# How to solve this Functional Equation: $f(x+1) - f(x) = e^{ax}$?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I have recently studied calculus of finite differences and I was wondering how to solve anti-differences for transcendental functions. Because I want to solve some interesting sums.

In this case, I want to solve the following functional equation below.

$f(x+1) - f(x) = e^{ax}$

Is there any general method in solving problems like this? I will highly appreciate a detailed answer!

Comment: Nope, I want to keep it as general as possible.

Comment: I am quite naive at recurrence relations so can you please tell me how?

Comment: Some telescopic work should help : $$f(x+n+1) - f(0) =\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{a(x+k)} $$ beiing geometric in order to study discrete limit. Then you may be able to study continous limits of your function it is a beginning

Comment: @PeterForeman Can you please elaborate more? I'm sorry for my ignorance. This stuff sounds alien to me. Sorry

Comment: What can you say about domain of $f$, for example, $\nexists$ continuous $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q} \iff f(x+1) \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'd like for its domain to be the set of real numbers, is it possible??

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast Any initial condition $f(x_0)=c$ gives a unique solution on the set $\{x\pm k:k\in\mathbb Z\}$. If you want a solution on all real numbers, you need a range of initial conditions, like knowing the value of $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1)$. This is essentially Gae. S' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x+1$ is not cyclic, there's no way (that I know of) to arrive at a set of equations you could solve. Unfortunately my solution is on the intuitive side, not sure how easy this method is to generalize.

Let's write $f(0)=c$. Now, substituting $x=0,1,2,...$ into the equation we get $f(1)=c+1$, $f(2)=c+1+e^a$, $f(3)=c+1+e^a+e^{2a}$ etc. In general, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$f(k)=c+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}e^{ia}=c+\frac{e^{ak}-1}{e^a-1}$$

Plugging $f(x)=c+\frac{e^{ax}-1}{e^a-1}$ into the functional equation, it is easy to work out that the identity holds.

Again, sorry for the hand-waving technique. Though summing up a series in this way could work for other functional equations of this type.

Comment: Why do you call this handwaving? You established the necessary condition and then showed that it is sufficient. The fact that you found a closed form for the sum is just the cherry on top, but it's not necessary, is it? Great answer, I think!

Comment: @Vincent I agree the solution is nice, but also it is not complete (that is probably what Avi considers an intuitive part). The reason is, you can have different constant $c$, based on where in the interval $[0,1)$ you start. So to have full solution, instead of having $c$, we should consider expression $g(\{x\})$ (where $\{\}$ is fractional part, and $g: [0,1) \to R$). This encapsulates all possible choices for constant within the unit interval, and is periodic for all remaining intervals. This answer basically shows the result for $g(x)\equiv c\in\mathbb{R}$, this is indeed a special case.

Comment: @Sil Yes, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Call $T_a$ the set of functions such that $f(x+1)-f(x)=e^{ax}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, and consider the map $\Phi_a:T_a\to \Bbb R^{[0,1)}$ defined by $\Phi_a(f)=\left.f\right\rvert_{[0,1)}$. $\Phi_a$ is a bijection, and specifically $$[\Phi_a^{-1}(g)](x)=\begin{cases}g(\{x\})+\frac{e^{a\{ x\}}-e^{ax}}{1-e^a}&\text{if }a\ne 0\\ g(\{x\})+\lfloor x\rfloor&\text{if }a=0\end{cases}$$

Where $\{x\}$ is the real number in $[0,1)$ such that $x-\{x\}\in\Bbb Z$, and $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\{x\}$ is the largest integer smaller or equal to $x$.

It is clear that $\Phi_a$ is injective and that $\left.\Phi_a^{-1}(g)\right\rvert_{[0,1)}=g$, therefore it is only a matter of verifying that $\Phi_a^{-1}(g)(x+1)-\Phi_a^{-1}(g)(x)=e^{ax}$ for all $x$, which is just algebra.

**Added:** Another approach is to notice that if you set $g(x)=f(x)+\frac{e^{ax}}{1-e^a}$ if $a\ne 0$ and $g(x)=f(x)-1$ if $a=0$, then you obtain that $g(x+1)=g(x)$, i.e. that the solutions are the functions in the form $\text{(1-periodic function)} +\frac{e^{ax}}{e^a-1}$.

Comment: Is $\Bbb R^{[0,1)}$ just . . . $[0,1)$?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Not by any means: it's the set of functions having domain $[0,1)$ and codomain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Gotchu! I forgot about that notation. It was making me think of $\Bbb R^+$ which is what I think tripped me up.